# Convolution - Heaviside

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, convolution

I'm having a hard time seeing how $\int_0^t f(u)H(t-u-1)du$ where H is the Heaviside function, is equal to $0$ for $t<1$ and $\int_0^{t-1}f(u)du$ for $t>1$. I know of course that $H(x)$ is generally zero for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x>0$ but I don't see what happened here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put the question in a form where $H(x)$ is considered explictly without compounding it with the linear map $u\mapsto t-u-1$. Consider the convolution integral and apply the change of variable $t-u-1\mapsto y$: then
$$
\begin{split}
\int\limits_0^t f(u)H(t-u-1)\mathrm{d}u &= \int\limits^{t-1}_{-1} f(t-y-1)H(y)\mathrm{d}y\\
& = \int\limits^{t-1}_{-1} f(t-y-1)H(y)\mathrm{d}y \\
& = 
\begin{cases}
0 & t\le 1\\
\\
\displaystyle\int\limits^{t-1}_{0} f(t-y-1)\mathrm{d}y & t >1
\end{cases} =
\begin{cases}
0 & t\le 1\\
\\
\displaystyle\int\limits^{t-1}_{0} f(u)\mathrm{d}u & t >1
\end{cases}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Hey, thank you. Care to explain the last equality? How did $t-y-1$ become $y$ inside $f$ ?

Comment: @Darkenin this is due to the fact that applying again the change of variables $t-y-1\mapsto u$ to the integral inside the first curly bracket we get
$$
\begin{split}
\int\limits^{t-1}_{0} f(t-y-1)\mathrm{d}y & = - \int\limits_{t-1}^{0} f(u)\mathrm{d}u\\
& = \int\limits^{t-1}_{0} f(u)\mathrm{d}u
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Whoops, I did that but forgot to reverse the limits so I kept getting that with a minus sign. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If $t<1$ then $t-u-1<0$ for all $u$ between $0$ and $t$ so $H(t-u-1)=0$ for all $u$ and hence the integral is $0$.

If $t>1$ then $H(t-u-1)=0$ for $u >t-1$ and  $H(t-u-1)=1$ for $u <t-1$ so the integral is effectively from $0$ to $t-1$.